# What does the given sentence mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence

In a games' description I found the following sentence:

> In this game, you will find mazes within mazes: your route to the
>   screen determining the route you trace across it.

This is a puzzle game where players come across hundreds of puzzles on an island. I am not sure about the purpose of the prepositions "to" and "across" in the part "your route to the screen determining the route you trace across it." I must be missing a very basic concept of the given game. Unfortunately, I cannot share more details due to confidentiality issues.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt you're missing a basic concept, it's more likely that someone rewrote this sentence partially or just was tired while writing it. The second part of the sentence does not make much sense, especially "route to the screen". Even if it made sense, it would be extremely convoluted and should be rewritten because instructions in general ought to be easily understandable to non-native English speakers.

I can recommend contacting the authors, I don't know the context, but in general it is considered reasonable to get in touch with the writer if the text you're working on is confusing, difficult or unclear.